# Typescript: filter an array containing every element of another array

Tags: typescript

I have the below array, with each module in the array has many classes assigned

```
const modules = [
   {
      "moduleId":"AN-01",
      "assignClasses":[
         {
            "class":{
               "classId":"1GC1"
            }
         },
         {
            "class":{
               "classId":"1A1"
            }
         },
         {
            "class":{
               "classId":"1EM1"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "moduleId":"CC-01",
      "assignClasses":[
         {
            "class":{
               "classId":"1A1"
            }
         },
         {
            "class":{
               "classId":"1EM1"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "moduleId":"CH-01",
      "assignClasses":[
         {
            "class":{
               "classId":"1GC1"
            }
         },
         {
            "class":{
               "classId":"1EM1"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to filter the above modules array which contains all the items that are in the elements array.

```
const elements = ["1GC1", "1EM1"];
```

I tried with the below code, but I get only the module CH-01, although it must return the modules AN-01 and CH-01.

```
let data = modules.filter(module => module.assignClasses.every(assign => elements.some(item => item == assign.class.classId)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const modules = [
   {
      "moduleId":"AN-01",
      "assignClasses":[
         {
            "class":{
               "classId":"1GC1"
            }
         },
         {
            "class":{
               "classId":"1A1"
            }
         },
         {
            "class":{
               "classId":"1EM1"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "moduleId":"CC-01",
      "assignClasses":[
         {
            "class":{
               "classId":"1A1"
            }
         },
         {
            "class":{
               "classId":"1EM1"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "moduleId":"CH-01",
      "assignClasses":[
         {
            "class":{
               "classId":"1GC1"
            }
         },
         {
            "class":{
               "classId":"1EM1"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
const elements = ["1GC1", "1EM1"];

let data = modules.filter(module => {
  const moduleClasses = module.assignClasses.map(assign => assign.class.classId)
  return elements.every(e => moduleClasses.includes(e))
}) 

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const result = modules.filter(module =>
    elements.every(el =>
    module.assignClasses.some(item => item.class.classId === el)));

console.log(result);
```